# Select an array with two columns, make sum of one column fixed and sum of the another column is minimum

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

this array have two columns, the first column means cbm, and second is price.

How to do the calculation: when I need a certain sum of cbm, and the lowest sum of price in the same time.

```
no    cbm     price     Y/N
 1    0.24     500 
 2    0.14     400 
 3    0.21     610 
 4    0.18     300 
 5    0.12     440 
 6    0.24     760
```

Results should be: which ones should be select to let the total cbm=0.8(+-0.08),and get the lowest price.

I'm thinking make third column filled with 0 or 1, (Find the number combinations whose sum of addition is closest to the certain value ), then do the total cost compare of each solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, what? i don't understand like half of your question, can you rewrite it properly?

Comment: I have ajusted the question just now.

Comment: Looks like this is linear programming problem. You can check out packages such as PuLP and Scipy

Answer (score 0):

thanks for crx91, and this is an linear programming problem-->Integer programming-->0-1 integer programming-->Knapsack problem.

Pulp package is useful, and below is a python code wrote by me, only for this simple quetion.( I'm thinking more complex conditions)

```py
    from pulp import *
    prob = LpProblem("re-assign", LpMinimize)
    weight=[0.25,0.32,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.45,0.46]
    cost=[120.2,148.2,120.2,120.2,125.9,120.2,120.2,120.2,120.2,120.2]
    
    status_metro=[LpVariable("x{}".format(i+1), cat="Binary") for i in range(len(weight))]
    
    prob +=pulp.lpSum([(i*cost1) for i ,cost1 in zip(status_metro,cost)])
    prob +=pulp.lpSum([(i*weight1) for i, weight1 in zip(status_metro,weight)])<=3.6
    prob +=pulp.lpSum([(i*weight1) for i , weight1 in zip(status_metro,weight)])>=3
    
    prob.solve()
    for v in prob.variables():
        print(v.name,"=",v.varValue)
    print("sum",pulp.value(prob.objective))
```